# ECommerce Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm currently going to be developing a database that will hold lots of items and was wondering which design would be better is there was 1000's to 10,000's of items per category.

Database Design #1

```
Login Details
--------------
-userID
-Username
-Password
- ETC....


User Settings
--------------
-userID
-Setting 1
-Setting 2
-Setting 3
- ETC....



Product Category
-----------------
-ID
-Name



ALL Items
-----------
-ItemID
-Name
-Description
-Price
-Info
- ETC....
-parentCategoryID
```

OR

Database Design #2

```
Login Details
--------------
-userID
-Username
-Password
- ETC....


User Settings
--------------
-userID
-Setting 1
-Setting 2
-Setting 3
- ETC....



Product Category
-----------------
-ID
-Name
-tableName



Electronics
-------------
-ItemID
-Name
-Desc.
-Price
- ETC....

Food
-------------
-ItemID
-Name
-Desc.
-Price
- ETC....


Books
-------------
-ItemID
-Name
-Desc.
-Price
- ETC....


Apparel
-------------
-ItemID
-Name
-Desc.
-Price
- ETC....



Others
-------------
-ItemID
-Name
-Desc.
-Price
- ETC....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 would be the way to go.

If you used option 2, you would have to use different queries each time you wished to query the database about a different product type for you would be storing different product types in different *tables*.

Storing users is much less problematic than storing products. As prices can change over time, it would be better to remove the 'price' field from the 'products' table and store it in a different table, 'pricelist', whose fields would be product, price, fromdate (and possibly tilldate).

Answer (score 1):

For option 2, you dont have referential integrity if you are going to depend on a string to identify the table.

Option 1 is , in my opinion , the well practiced (normalized) way of doing things. Moreover, even holding 10000 rows per category is not a big deal for modern databases.

Comment: I could hard code an file that contains database names, but for option 1 would 10 categories of ~1m items ea (total of ~10million) items be ok for 1 table in a database?

Comment: Need to know what kind of queries will be common.

Comment: Searching by:  "Item name"  "item name and Category"  "by isbn(books)" and search search will also be able to sort by price